# Edit and continue does not work anymore

Tags: visual-studio, edit, continue

I got recently problems with VisualStudio, when trying to debug and edit:

Changes not allowed when unmanaged debugging is enabled?

I have checked all projects of my solutions and all list this:

Find all "EnableUnmanagedDebugging", Subfolders, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution"
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 5030

So I do not have selected unmanaged debugging. I also looked in Debug options. I have set the flag enable just my code. I tried to reset it, but it did not help.

Has anyone an idea, where I may look at to find out how to switch it on?
I am not working alone on the solution, so the change may have happend through another person, I do not know of.

Best regards,

Patrick

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using—2008, 2010, 11, etc.? Are you building an ASP.NET project, a C++ project, a C# project, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. There was a project with unmanaged code debugging switched on. Unfortunately it was the start project. I do not know, why the file search did not show the project file, but if you have a similar problem, you need to check the projects.

Best regards,

Patrick